# Delete From Table Name Stored As Variable?

Tags: php, mysql

After the user logs out, it basically deletes the all the data in their table that includes their id code in any of the rows.

```
$idcode = $_SESSION['idcode'];
$idicao = $_SESSION['idicao'];

if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {

$sql = "DELETE FROM $idicao WHERE idcode=".$idcode."";

mysql_query($sql);

}


session_unset();
session_destroy();

mysql_close($dbid);

header("Location: login.php");

?>
```

The variables are echoed on the page correctly, and session_start is at the top. The only problem is that the records from the tables are not being deleted.

Comment: you say all variables echoed correctly.. does that include $_POST['logout'] ?

Comment: echo $sql, show us the result.

Comment: echoing $sql gives me DELETE FROM Test WHERE idcode=test

Comment: and $_POST['logout'] is correctly echoed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying that the sql-variable outputs: DELETE FROM Test WHERE idcode=test

Test should be in single quotes like this:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM ".$idicao." WHERE idcode='".$idcode."'";
```

Answer (score 2):

change this line:
`$sql = "DELETE FROM $idicao WHERE idcode=".$idcode."";`

to

`$sql = "DELETE FROM ".$idicao." WHERE idcode=".$idcode.";`

and you should be good to go

Comment: the query seems to be fixed now, as echoing $sql gives me DELETE FROM Test WHERE idcode=test. But Its not going through.

Comment: OK, so what is the name of the table you are deleting from? and what is the column name?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$idicao='yourtablename';   
$sql = 'DELETE FROM '.$idicao.' WHERE idcode='.$idcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM ? WHERE idcode = ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $idicao, $idcode);
$stmt->execute();
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                              $obj->error = 'Error: ...your error msg...';
                              echo json_encode($obj);
                              exit;
}
```